# Will I have problems if i implement a newsletter using PHP $mail?

Tags: php, email, newsletter, mailing

I mean,

i'n the long term, when i have many accounts (10,000+), will send them all?

Or better i find a 3rd party open script for this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know, if you send a lot of email all at the same moment, you can get blacklisted by mail hosters as a spammer. One solution i heard about is to delay and send one smaller batch from every hour or so, but i honnestly don't think this is really efficient ;)

Using an external partner could be useful, maybe you could try Mail Chimp, as it is free with limit of 2k users, i guess it's worth giving a try. Then if you go over 2k you can consider getting a paying service or not !

Comment: Seconded. Not worth the trouble of taking care of the logistics yourself, especially if you are not well versed in deliverability. MailChimp is the de facto solution for newsletters. Mad Mimi is a good alternative as well.

Comment: I case i use a 3rd party, can i sen them new adress vía mail? or only through their button?